# Elegant list comprehension to extract values in one dimension of an array based on values in another dimension

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension

I'm looking for an elegant solution to this:

```
data = np.loadtxt(file)
# data[:,0] is a time
# data[:,1] is what I want to extract
mean = 0.0
count = 0
for n in xrange(np.size(data[:,0])):
    if data[n,0] >= tstart and data[n,0] <= tend:
        mean = mean + data[n,1]
        count = count + 1

mean = mean / float(count)
```

I'm guessing I could alternatively first extract my 2D array and then apply `np.mean` on it but I feel like there could be some list comprehension goodness to make this more elegant (I come from a FORTRAN background...). I was thinking something like (obviously wrong since `i` would not be an index):

```
np.mean([x for x in data[i,1] for i in data[:,0] if i >= tstart and i <= tend])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In numpy, rather than listcomps you can use lists and arrays for indexing purposes.  To be specific, say we have a 2D array like the one you're working with:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = np.arange(20).reshape(10, 2)
>>> data
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 8,  9],
       [10, 11],
       [12, 13],
       [14, 15],
       [16, 17],
       [18, 19]])
```

We can get the first column:

```
>>> ts = data[:,0] 
>>> ts
array([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18])
```

And create a boolean array corresponding to the terms we want:

```
>>> (ts >= 2) & (ts <= 6)
array([False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Then we can use this to select elements of the column we're interested in:

```
>>> data[:,1][(ts >= 2) & (ts <= 6)]
array([3, 5, 7])
```

and finally take its mean:

```
>>> np.mean(data[:,1][(ts >= 2) & (ts <= 6)])
5.0
```

Or, in one line:

```
>>> np.mean(data[:,1][(data[:,0] >= 2) & (data[:,0] <= 6)])
5.0
```

[Edit: `data[:,1][(data[:,0] >= 2) & (data[:,0] <= 6)].mean()` will work too; I always forget you can use methods.]

Comment: Thanks I think that does the job perfectly ! Didn't think about multiplying my array of number by an array of booleans to extract my data. Got a long way to go before thinking like this...

Comment: @FrenchKheldar: You're not multiplying, you're using an array of booleans as an index.  It's probably worth reading through the numpy tutorial, there are some nice indexing tricks that can make your life a lot simpler.

Comment: I wouldn't put it like that (numpy has masked arrays and they're something different), though I know what you mean.  If you have an ordinary list, you could do `d[4]` and get the element with index 4.  With numpy, the indexing is simply more powerful, so you can select multiple elements.